# I am a black belt at or black belt in?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> I am a Black Belt at Origami. One false move and I can fold you into
> twelve.!” Petrá joked. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=RRYSEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=%22i+am+a+black+belt+at%22&source=bl&ots=ayB32zPACl&sig=ACfU3U2JhE6Sf1TPTVkey2vnNGKk1fQMsQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjokrX50saDAxXIIjQIHYZWD6E4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22i%20am%20a%20black%20belt%20at%22&f=false))

I am pretty sure you can't say at unless it's a location. What do you think? I am a black belt at cooking, I am a black belt in cooking or both?

I see at used a lot though in [certain context.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22black%20belt%20at%20karate%22&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=595989641&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz07j-08aDAxVZJzQIHeYQCqIQ_AUoAXoECAMQCw&biw=1919&bih=1206&dpr=0.8)

Comment: Please look up "at" in Merriam Webster. It is a function word in several ways and is not always location. "Am I good at this"? However, in your sentence, "in" is better. Are you good at cooking?

Comment: Anecdotally, I usually hear "in" for this usage, but it's not out of the question that "at" _may_ be acceptable - one normally does say things like "I am good _at_ cooking/writing computer programs/etc.".

Comment: Also, I know some students of martial arts whose senseis are quite traditional, and they're more likely to say something like "I have attained  fourth kyu" or "I have attained second dan", rather than giving a belt color.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I will never forget _Her name is Yoshimi/She's a black belt in karate_.

Comment: It is against all manner of/in/at law to dissect a joke at length. Petra has no origami Black Belt at all, and so cannot be an expert of/in/at origami. At the moment, **is joke**. Three examples of *at* that point, but without location.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on a comment:

> I am pretty sure you can't say at unless it's a location

What probably inspired the example you found is the phrase "[to be] good at [something]," or many similar ones with synonyms of "good": "I'm skilled at cooking," "I'm amazing at knitting," "I'm the best at yard maintenance."

"Black belt" is a rank or level, and these aren't normally this way. You're right that martial arts ranks often pair with "in": "Her name is Yoshimi / She's a black belt in karate." Academic credentials often use "in" when speaking of the degree itself, though some use "of" when used to describe the person who holds them: "I have a master's degree in engineering", "She's a doctor of medicine."

The fact that you found a usage breaking these patterns shows that you can't claim that you *can't* use it this way. But scanning the surrounding prose shows many other non-standard or awkward usages, so I wouldn't be too concerned over this instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a *lot* of contexts in English where one possibility - EITHER the "container" metaphoric usage *(**in**)* OR the "location" usage *(**at**)* - is far more common than the other. But that rarely if ever implies the less common choice is "syntactically incorrect".

The first ["slightly unusual"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20black%20belt%20in%2Ca%20black%20belt%20at%2Ca%20Black%20Belt%20in%2Ca%20Black%20Belt%20at&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) thing I noticed about OP's example wasn't the preposition anyway - it was the *capitalization...*

[image]

I don't say OP's capitalization is incorrect. But by the same token I can't endorse OP saying people who choose the less common preposition are incorrect.

Comment: "a *lot* of contexts"... but I notice you cut the scale off your copied and pasted ngram. Not that the scale is volume anyway, but frequency.

Comment: I don't understand why you would "notice" that I advanced the chart date from its default 1800 to 1960. Looking at the "area under the curve" of the "full" chart, it seems that well over 99% of all written instances of ***black belt*** are contained within the date range I *did* show. If I'd left it at the default you'd hardly see anything before 1960 anyway, but if I'd charted, say, 1800-1950, that would have given a misleading impression - simply because many Victorian writers / publishers routinely capitalized many "important" nouns. But we don't do that today.